# Smarty: Always show 3 digit numbers

Tags: smarty, prestashop

This may be a easy question to answer but I am a bit stumped and I have not studied Smarty long enough to figure it out.

I need to display numbers in a 3 digit format, ie:

```
8   = 008
18  = 018
118 = 118
```

To add some context, basically I am trying to edit a Prestashop template (never touched smarty before this).  Currently the price is displayed as 1.223.014 and I would like to separate the last three digits so that I can format it differently from the first part of the price. Thus I would be able to do something like

```
<span class="abc">1.223</span>.<span class="xyz">014</span>
```

Not sure if there is a easier way to do this but basically I am currently dividing the current price by 1000 (to eliminate the last 3 digits) and now I am stumped on how to get the last 3 digits (works fine if the last three digits are above 99)

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for your example
`{"%03d"|sprintf:8}`

Possible solution if you want the last 3 digits in any case
`{'1.223.014'|substr:-3}`

html:

```
<span class="abc">{'1.223.014'|substr:0:-4}</span>.<span class="xyz">{'1.223.014'|substr:-3}</span>
```

**Note: This will not work if the number length is lower than 4**

If you wanna check if there are dots inside the number, you can do this

```
{if '1.223.014'|substr_count:'.' > 0}
..dots inside..
{else}
..no dots inside..
{/if}
```

Tested with smarty 3.